# Texto "visualizações" sobrepõe o layout do site

Tags: bug, status-pronto

A palavra "visualizações" está estourando o *layout* no Google Chrome no OS X:
 (A palavra "respostas" também está ficando cortada)

O que pode ser feito? Alterar a largura dos elementos? Abreviar? Usar o termo *"views"* em inglês? Mexer com o espaçamento do texto?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Na imagem também dá para ver que "respostas" está comendo o padding.

Comment: Eu imagino que essas coisas são visíveis por todos e a equipe já devem estar providenciando uma solução. Eles não sabem bem como é complicado localizar de software :D

Comment: ;D Sim. Especialmente para português que é em geral bem mais longo que inglês. Se fosse para por exemplo chinês ou japonês, ficaria era sobrando espaço, e os problemas seriam no geral de encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Melhorou agora?

Os devs só precisam de 2 horas pra consertar 1 palavra! Eles trabalham duro :D

Comment: Wooot! Notei que a tradução das medalhas também chegou nesse meio tempo. Fantástico :D

Comment: Foi muito rápido, alguma coisa vai quebrar :)

Comment: Várias coisas *já* quebraram!

Comment: Fui brincar mas é sério, embora seja outro bug. Na página que lista as perguntas (não a home) você vê os votos, a quantidade de de respostas e depois as visualizações abaixo. Lá continua a palavra *visualizações*, ficou inconsistente e vai quebrar se o número ficar muito grande (pode até não quebrar quando milhares virar K, mas não sei se não quebra com 200K.

Comment: @bigown Não tinha condições de revisar **todas** as ocorrências de *visuzalições* hoje. Corrigimos a mais gritante e o resto vai vindo com o tempo. Você pode postar essa como bug de tradução?

Comment: Estou anotando vários erros que vejo. Eu prefiro postar tudo de uma vez. Você acha que é melhor fazer um por um? Eu acho mais trabalhoso e abriria uma quantidade imensa de questões muito semelhantes, porque tem muita coisa com problemas ainda. Até consigo ver vantagem em colocar um por um, mas vejo muitas desvantagens também, uma delas é que vai cansar todo mundo logo.

Comment: Não tem problema juntar tudo num post só, só tentar evitar criar um post com 60 problemas diferentes... Mas lembre-se que a localização **ainda não acabou**, então seria melhor focar em coisas que poderiam ser melhores do que em coisas que ainda estão 100% em inglês.

Comment: De fato não estou tão preocupado com a tradução, provavelmente vou falar de algo que vai acabar sendo resolvido em algum momento. Falta de tradução eu não vou falar a não ser que seja algo que é fundamental que esteja traduzido. É perda de tempo até que a equipe defina que tudo esteja pronto, aí se falhar alguma coisa, vale abrir uma questão para isso. Erros já tem uma pressa maior, mas não muito também.

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção seria mudar a palavra, o que pode não ser muito bom ou fácil.

[image: Mudar palavra]

Uma outra opção seria abreviar e/ou colocar como `overflow: hidden`

[image: overflow hidden]

E desta forma não quebraria o layout, não importando o idioma, para ler o texto inteiro poderia colocar um atributo `title="visualizações"`.

Comment: "acessos" é uma boa!

Comment: Concordo que "acessos" é uma boa, mas "resp." fica meio feio.

Comment: Abreviações ficam bem feias. Não gosto muito do "acessos" também, mas não vejo nada melhor no momento.

Comment: Como tem gente mais inteligente que nós, ficou *visitas* :) Que é melhor embora não perfeito também. Estou sendo pedante? :)

Comment: Pensei em visitas, mas achei estranho, assim como acessos também. Bem, é uma solução para agora, mas e se algum dia tiver um SO em outro idioma, vai ter uma palavra curta também?